# using async.js with node.js streams

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, stream, coffeescript, pipe

I want to use asyn.js for limiting the number of parallel io operations. I have come across the following example:

```
async.forEachLimit items, 5, ((item, next) ->
  request item.url, (error, response, body) ->
    console.log body
    next error)
    , (err) ->
        throw err  if err
        console.log "All requests processed!"
```

But I want to use it with streams, like this:

```
async.forEachLimit items, 5, ((item, next)->
    stream = fs.createWriteStream file
    request.get(item.url).pipe(stream))
    , (err)->
          throw err  if err
          console.log "All requests processed!"
```

How do I place the 'next' call when the writestream is done writing to file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to bind to the Readable Stream's [`'end'` event](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_end) separate from the `.pipe()`.

```
res = request.get(item.url)
res.pipe(stream)
res.on 'end', next
```

This also lets you bind to its `'error'` event:

```
res.on 'error', next
```

But, you could also listen to the Writable Stream's [`'finish'` event](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_finish):

```
request.get(item.url)
    .on 'finish', next
```

Comment: This is why I love SO. Thank you so much!

Comment: Quick question. Shouldn't I listen to the finish event on the writable stream, since that follows the readable stream? If I listen for the end event on the readable stream, I might end up calling 'next' before writestream gets done.

Comment: @tldr Yeah, it's possible. The writable stream can buffer, so the readable stream ends first. So, `'finish'` would probably be better. Though, you'll still need `res` for an `'error'` event.